# NAudio SampleProvider not updating buffer on Read as expected

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to use Naudio to input audio and then output it again after it has been processed by a plugin. To do the output step I have created a custom SampleProvider but the buffer is not behaving as I expect and I can't hear any sound. The code that reads the audio and attempts to play it again is as follows

```
var audioFile = new AudioFileReader(@"C:\Users\alex.clayton\Downloads\Rhythm guitar.mp3");

PluginContext.PluginCommandStub.Commands.MainsChanged(true);
PluginContext.PluginCommandStub.Commands.StartProcess();

var vstSampleProvider = new VstSampleProvider(44100, 2);
var devices = DirectSoundOut.Devices.Last();
var output = new DirectSoundOut(devices.Guid);
output.Init(vstSampleProvider);

int chunckStep = 0;
while (chunckStep < audioFile.Length)
{
    var nAudiobuffer = new float[blockSize * 2];
    audioFile.Read(nAudiobuffer, 0, blockSize * 2);

    var leftSpan = inputMgr.Buffers.ToArray()[0].AsSpan();
    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++)
    {
        leftSpan[i] = nAudiobuffer[i*2] / int.MaxValue;
    }

    var rightSpan = inputMgr.Buffers.ToArray()[0].AsSpan();
    for (int i = 1; i < blockSize; i++)
    {
        rightSpan[i] = nAudiobuffer[i*2 + 1] / int.MaxValue;
    }

    PluginContext.PluginCommandStub.Commands.ProcessReplacing(inputBuffers, outputBuffers);

    vstSampleProvider.LoadBuffer(outputBuffers);

    chunckStep += blockSize;
}
PluginContext.PluginCommandStub.Commands.StopProcess();
PluginContext.PluginCommandStub.Commands.MainsChanged(false);

output.Play();
```

The Sample provider code is this

```
public class VstSampleProvider : ISampleProvider
{
    private readonly int _sampleRate;
    private readonly int _channels;
    private readonly Queue<float> _buffer;

    public VstSampleProvider(int sampleRate, int channels)
    {
        _sampleRate = sampleRate;
        _channels = channels;
        _buffer = new Queue<float>();
    }

    public WaveFormat WaveFormat => WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(_sampleRate, _channels);

    public void LoadBuffer(VstAudioBuffer[] outputBuffers)
    {
        var totalSampleCount = outputBuffers[0].SampleCount * _channels;

        try
        {
            if (_channels == 1)
                for (int i = 0; i < totalSampleCount; i++)
                {
                    _buffer.Enqueue(outputBuffers[0][i]);
                }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < totalSampleCount; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        var value = outputBuffers[0][i / 2];
                        _buffer.Enqueue(value);
                    }
                    else
                        _buffer.Enqueue(outputBuffers[1][(i - 1) / 2]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Probably should log or something
        }
    }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (_buffer.Count < count)
            return 0;

        if (offset > 0)
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var value = _buffer.Dequeue();
            buffer[i] = value;
        }

        if (buffer.Any(f => f > 1))
        {
            return count;
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

When I look at the values being dequeued they are all between -1 and 1, as expected but when I put a break point on the line after `if (buffer.Any(f => f > 1))` I can see that the buffer values are integers larger than 1 or 0 and bear no resemblance to the dequeued values that, I thought, were added to the buffer.

I expect I have not understood something about how the SampleProvider is supposed to work byt looing at ones already in Naudio I cant see what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the main issue was reading the input file and turning the volume down, so I was playing but very quietly.

```
leftSpan[i] = nAudiobuffer[i*2] / int.MaxValue
```

There was no need for the `/ int.MaxValue`